# Strong Law of Large Numbers a.s. sense implies $L^1$ sense?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I have to show that the strong law of large numbers in the almost sure sense implies the strong law of large numbers in the $L^1$ sense. I'm not sure what's being asked, can anyone give me a hint or explanation?